# Error: Cannot find the outlet myteam_outlet to load 'MemberListingComponent'

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have tried all solutions given in SO but no luck. My situation is different.

In main component I have an outlet where child module is loaded. i have defined child routes in the child module:

```
 RouterModule.forChild([
  { path: '', component: MyTeamComponent },
  { path: 'members', component: MemberListingComponent , outlet: 'myteam_outlet'}
])
```

default path `{ path: '', component: MyTeamComponent }` loades below html:

```
<div class="col-md-2 row">
  <md-toolbar color="primary">
    <md-toolbar-row>
      <a md-button [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { myteam_outlet: ['members'] } }]"
      [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']">Members Listing</a>
    </md-toolbar-row>

    <md-toolbar-row>
      <a md-button>Attendance</a>
    </md-toolbar-row>
  </md-toolbar>
</div>

<div class="col-md-10">
  <router-outlet name="myteam_outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

in above HTML you can see I have a named outlet. here I want to load MemberListingComponent when `<a md-button [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { myteam_outlet: ['members'] } }]"[routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']">Members Listing</a>` is clicked, but keep getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After waiting for answer and searching on google. I have solved my problem.

i was using a child outlet and trying to load child components but the route is not on the same level as router outlet is. Routing should be:

```
RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: '', component: MyTeamComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'members', component: MemberListingComponent }
    ]
  }
])
```

(**route** and **router-outlet** is on the same level now)

Now it will find my child outlet and load component in it if i do `this.router.navigate(['myteam/members']);`. also don't need to name the router outlet.

Comment: Now you just made my day! Thanks for posting it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I trapped on this problem before, Then I put my `router-outlet` code in the template of app.module.ts, and put this code below the main `router-outlet`.

```
<div class="col-md-10">
  <router-outlet name="myteam_outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

hope it will work for you.

my code description is below where i used `router-outlet` :

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component,OnInit,Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  moduleId: module.id,
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css','dashboard.component.css'],
  template: ` <h1  highlight>{{title}}</h1>
  <nav>

    <button [disabled]='!isDisabled' [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { popup: ['compose'] } }]">Contact</button>

  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
`,
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(public router:Router,private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) {}

title:String;
isDisabled:Boolean;
currentUrl:String;
checkAdmin:boolean=true;

  @Output()  adminUrl:String;
  ngOnInit() {
  this.title = 'SHUBHAM | Angular 2';
  this.isDisabled=true;
  this.currentUrl="";
  console.log(this.currentUrl);
};
}
```

**app.routing.ts:**

```
import { NgModule                    }    from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes 
        ,Router , ActivatedRoute,PreloadingStrategy
                                      }    from '@angular/router';
import { ComposeMessageComponent      }    from './compose-message.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'compose',                     component: ComposeMessageComponent, outlet: 'popup'  },

];
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes),HeroRoutingModule ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
  providers: [CanDeactivateGuard ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: I have already did what you have suggested. but I want to load component in the outlet which is in a template of child module. according to ur suggestion i have to put my child outlet with same level of main outlet, that will be messy if I have multiple child nested outlet.